# All Excel files renamed from 'filename.xlsx' to 'filename1.xlsx'

Tags: microsoft-excel

my files open fine in Excel but the app renames them. Them whenever I want to save, it goes through this bs where I need to go all the way back to the original location and save over the original file. Sure it's not that bad once or twice but it happens 50 times a day! Please help!

Comment: Check they've not been set to read only & you have write perms in the save folder. That's the kind of behaviour you get with a template or locked file

Comment: Thanks man. Is there an 'everything is a template' setting in excel? The files aren't locked/readonly

Comment: Also I noticed, once re-saved for a file, it doesn't happen again for that file as long as it's kept open. weird.

Comment: I don't know, tbh - it just seems like it's that type of behaviour.

Comment: If you rename 'filename1.xlsx' to 'filename.xlsx', does it happen again?

Comment: Yep it still occurs. It's strange because Excel never did this at work or my old PC.

Comment: Re-install Ms Office should do. Seems like your case is bound to the Ms Excel default way of handling new file .. if the error resides in Ms Office setting this should happen for Ms Word & PowerPoint too.. Since it happens only to Ms Excel (and there is no way afaik to clean re-install Ms Excel only), and you have a valid license, a re-install Ms Office is the thing to do. | Pls if it works/not..

Comment: Thanks ! I uninstalled, now there's no problem at all. completely :)

Comment: Excel has a setting 'open as read-only by default'. Somewhere, I don't remember where. It was probably active.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't found a setting likat that yet. However, if the file is opened inside Excel the problem doesn't occur. If I double-click in Windows then it opens as 'filename1.xlsx'...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for the ideas!

In the end I figured there's some problem with the shell setup, so I exported then deleted the entire node:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Sheet.12\shell
```

Then remapped it in Windows for the first-time open.. worked like a charm.